# Accord support for DirectShow

Tags: accord.net

The Accord functions for Accord.Video.DirectShow seem not to work anymore under the new MS VS 2022 IDE and .NET 7.0 or more recent.

Will these functions will be updated so that they can be used for Window C# Applications again ?

Regards
Wolfgang Kurz  ( 04/2023 )